# Save ogg stream provided by AWS Polly into a wav file

Tags: java, audio, wav, amazon-polly, audioinputstream

I am trying to create a webpage, where user will be able to listen to the text he types. I also want to provide a functionality to download the media in `.wav` format.

I am able to get `AudioStream` from `AmazonPollyClient` but not able to save the stream to `.wav` file.

Here is what I am trying...

```
public void convertToWav(SynthesizeSpeechResult result, File convertedFile) throws IOException {

    try (AudioInputStream sias = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(result.getAudioStream())){

        AudioFormat newFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 8000f, 16, 1, 2, 8000f, false);
        AudioInputStream convert1AIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(newFormat, sias);

        AudioSystem.write(convert1AIS, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, convertedFile);

        convert1AIS.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.gc();
}
```

but everytime I call `getAudioInputStream()` it throws `IOException`

```
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
    at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:348)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:112)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.reset(ProgressInputStream.java:168)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:139)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
```

P.S: I have tried wrapping `result.getAudioStream()` in `BufferedInputStream()`. No show!

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out way to save `InputStream` provided by `polly-aws-sdk`

```
public static boolean getWavFile(String filePath, InputStream audioStream) throws IOException {

    boolean result = false;
    try {

        byte[] decodedData = IOUtils.toByteArray(audioStream);

        System.out.println(">>Decoded Data" + Arrays.toString(decodedData));
        File outFile = new File(filePath);
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000, 16, 1, true, false);
        AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                decodedData), format, decodedData.length), AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outFile);
        result = true;
        return result;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("<<getWavFile - impl" + ex);
        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: I have used the same method as above but the audio file that is generating is containing buzzing noise only. do you have any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: i was using OutputFormat.MP3 so it was not working, now when i changed it to OutputFormat.Pcm it worked. Thanks